# Cannot add post and images value into database

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm trying to add text and images using

Image is successfully added into folder path. but the value of text and images did not add into database

```
<?php

    function insertpost(){
        global $connect;
        if(isset($_POST['sendpost']))
        {
            $title                 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST["title"]);
            $target_image          = "images/".basename($_FILES['post_image']['name']);
            $post_image            = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];

            $insert_post_and_image = "INSERT INTO table(title, image) VALUES ('$title','$post_image')";
            mysqli_query($connect, $insert_post_and_image);

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'], $target_image))
                {
                        echo "<h3>Posted to timeline!</h3>";
                }
        }   
    }
?>
```

html code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="text" name="title"/>
                        <input type="file" name="post_image"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="sendpost" value="POST"/> 
</form>
```

any solution? thanks

Comment: @Rozaimi.can you show the database table.Also in your query ur using table instead of that use real name

Comment: still finding the answer bro . :) just run and test the sql , it works . but when i apply into code. it doesnt work. sorry for the late reply :)

Comment: This could surely be solved with some basic debugging techniques. I'd start with `var_dump($connect);`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistake in `table` name in your query .Just replace table with your actual table name.For example if you have defined table name as user then your query must be

```
$insert_post_and_image = "INSERT INTO user(title, image) VALUES ('$title','$post_image')";
```

Also you can check error using

```
if (mysqli_query($connect, $insert_post_and_image)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connect);
}
```

Comment: I doubt very much that `table` is their actual table name, after seeing some of their past questions that contain the name `table.`

Comment: nope. already check the sql statement , when i remove image function . the post can be added into database . but when i try to include image code into th line. it doesnt work . only images store into path folder

Comment: @Fred-ii-.okay.Thanks

Comment: @Rozaimi.just try to print post image before query and also check for errors as i updated in the answer

Answer (score 0):

*correction 
Hi, already found the answer . i'm not sure if it's correct or not . please advise. thanks :)

```
<?php

    function insertpost(){
        global $connect;
        if(isset($_POST['sendpost']))
        {
            $title                 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST["title"]);
            $target_image          = "images/".basename($_FILES['post_image']['name']);
            $post_image            = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];

            $insert_post_and_image = "INSERT INTO table(title, image) VALUES ('$title','$post_image')";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $insert_post_and_image);

                if($result)     
                {
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'], $target_image);
                        echo "<h3>Posted to timeline!</h3>";
                }
        }   
    }
?>
```